# Need help in android screen-orientation

Tags: android, android-orientation

I having trouble in my demo application.
Please check the screens i attached,
 
 [image: Portrait View][image: Landscape View]
 I want **Activity A** only in portrait view (should not change in landscape mode), So i declared `ScreenOrientation="protrait"` in manifest file and **Activity B** (theme is dialog) should be changed in any mode (portrait or landscape), But when i move my phone in landscape mode **Activity B** does not changes its orientation.

Activity A

```
package com.example.activityorientation;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Intent it = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),DialogAct.class);
        startActivity(it);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Activity B

```
package com.example.activityorientation;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class DialogAct extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.dailogact);
    }
}
```

Manifest file,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.activityorientation"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.activityorientation.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.activityorientation.DialogAct"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"/>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Need help,
thanks.

Comment: Please check ur mobile settings. Unknowingly you may have locked ur screen orientation functionality in mobile

Comment: @SankarV i think you did not understood my question, my orientation function works fine, but i want Activity A only with portrait mode and  Activity B's View should be change in any mode. but it not changed into landscape view. please check again my screens

Comment: put this in your manifest below that activity android:configChanges="screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"

Comment: @Deen Sorry android:configChanges="screenLayout|screenSize|orientation" not worked i checked it in both activites.

Comment: not sure, but can it help if you use activity B as a fragment?

Comment: @bofredo no i have to use activity B as Theme.Dialog.. making it as a fragment would be last option.

Answer (score 0):

Override `onConfigurationChanges()` method in your activity. Hope it may help you.

And put this in your manifest below that activity `android:configChanges="screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"`

Comment: Thanks for reply deen, i overide nConfigurationChanges() method in Activity B, and also put android:configChanges="screenLayout|screenSize|orientation" in manifest but still not working..

Comment: try to overide it on launcher too

Comment: ohh. ok try to put this for your dialog activity android:screenOrientation="fullSensor"

Comment: Well it changes both activities in landscape or portrait mode, but i want to make change only in activity B and activity A should be viewed only in portrait.

Comment: ok remove that one and set configChanges mode in your dialog activity throug codeing

Comment: for launcher activity setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT|ActivityInfo.CONFIG_SCREEN_LAYOUT|ActivityInfo.CONFIG_SCREEN_SIZE|ActivityInfo.CONFIG_ORIENTATION); for dialog activity setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_FULL_SENSOR);

Comment: No @Deen still both activity changes its view as per its orientation.

Comment: ok then try it for dialog activity only setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.CONFIG_ORIENTATION)

Comment: Now both activities views only in portrait view.. no change

Comment: replace this line Intent it = new Intent(youractivity.this,DialogAct.class);

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried---->

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.activityorientation.DialogAct"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
        android:screenOrientation="fullsensor"/>
```

Comment: yes i tried.. but it changes both activities in landscape or portrait mode, but i want to make change only in activity B and activity A should be viewed only in portrait.

Comment: I am not sure but try this--> `Intent it = new Intent(this,DialogAct.class);`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait|sensorLandscape"` in **Activity B**.

Comment: Have you tried  -- <activity android:name="com.example.activityorientation.DialogAct" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait|sensorLandscape" />

Comment: i am not able to compile my application gives error in manifest.... error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'screenOrientation' with value 'sensorPortrait|
 sensorLandscape')... i guess we can't write both sensorPortrait|
 sensorLandscape

Comment: Adding both shouldn't be a problem. Check this link -- http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#screen

Comment: I recommend adding v4 support library jars -- http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html#SettingUp -- and try compiling the code. Since sensorLandscape and sensorPortrait attributes are supported since API level 9.

Comment: i already added v4 support library & using API level 17.. sensorLanscape or sensorPortrait works but both togather not working.. and in your given link they clearly mentioned ..The value can be any one of the following strings:.. please check.. thnks :)

Answer (score 0):

When an Not Full screen activity is launched on top with unspecified orientation(default) , it follows the orientation of Full screen activity which behind it in pause mode.
But if we deliberately specify the orientation value for not full screen activity, it will also force the orientation of Full screen activity which behind it in pause mode to change along with it.

Activity B is not a full screen activity.
So, When we launch Activity B , Activity A goes in Pause mode only.
Now for such case scenario, 
if for Activity B screen orientation is unspecified or not defined, it will in same orientation as activity A.
If you deliberately specify the screen orientation of Activity B to Landscape , it will change the activity A also to landscape mode.

i suggest to make Activity B full activity.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. but in my case i must have put Activity B as Theme.Dailog..

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in your OnCreate().

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

Example of OnCreate() method (working):

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        **setUIComponents();**
}
public void setUIComponents() {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ccap);
        **setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);**
        firstName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.firstNameEditText);
        middleName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        lastName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        bussinessName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.bussinessNameEditText);
        DOB = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.DOB);
        updateTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        this.countyNumber = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.countySpinner);
        this.numberPerPage = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.itemsPerPageSpinner);
        popSpinner();
        submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        onSubmit();
    }
```

Above code is working in my Activity; try this code in whichever Activity you want to stay "Portrait". Also if you want different orientations just change `ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT` to something else like `ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;`

Specifically for you, this should work:

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR);
```

**EDIT**

This should work:

```
package com.example.activityorientation;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
**setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);**

        Intent it = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),DialogAct.class);
        startActivity(it);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Now in Actvity B:

```
package com.example.activityorientation;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class DialogAct extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.dailogact);
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not working as i want... both activity changes its view as per its orientation..but i want to make change only in activity B by changing its orientation and activity A should be viewed only in portrait.

Comment: Try setting Activity A setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

then set Activity B
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR);

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and it is help me:
Add in AndroidManifest for Activity B

```
android:screenOrientation="fullSensor"
```

Answer (score -1):

Put below line in your `AndroidManifest.xml` in Activity B.

```
 android:configChanges="orientation"
```

It will work in both orientation.

OR

Check your mobile settings or check is motion is on of your device.

Comment: @pratik.. sorry android:configChanges="orientation" not worked.. and i checked in settings orientation function is working well.